# Translating text with browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, translation, google-translate, userscripts

I want to create a userscript that works like bot. I'm looking to see if I can translate a word or paragraph using a browser console like chrome or firefox.

I've tried using **npm** ([google-translate-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api)) + [Browserify](https://browserify.org) but can not, maybe because **npm** can only use server nodes or other ...

(I do not really want to use a **paid** google translate **API** or other * because it's just a small project)

if you guys have a clue it might be really helpful to me.

Comment: Your question is very unclear (and also off-topic for Stack Overflow).  I suggest just searching for a translation API that meets your requirements.  Also, before posting questions you should really read **[ask]**

Comment: Can you provide more details about your request? Are you trying to translate your own website, or you would like to translate the websites you're visiting?